# Iterate through parameters and optional values in a case class checking that only certain fields are defined

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a case class like the following except it has far more parameters (all optional):

```
case class MyClass(i: Option[String], j: Option[Int], n: Option[OtherClass])
```

I want to loop over the parameters and verify that only i and j are defined, while the rest are None. If the case class changes in the future I want to keep the same validation in place, which is why I am not using pattern matching or explicitly checking.

What is a good a way of doing this in scala 2.12?

Comment: No chance you can use Scala 2.13? If so you could use `productElementNames` and `productIterator` to easily do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `productIterator` which is a list of fields for the `case class`:

```
def verify(mc: MyClass) = {
  val c = mc.productIterator.count{
    case o: Option[_] => o.nonEmpty
      case _ => true
  }

  mc.i.nonEmpty && mc.j.nonEmpty && c == 2
}
```

However this kind of generic code has risks, so I would recommend avoiding a `case class` with a lot of fields. Consider grouping various fields into their own object and the making the test explicit on the known fields.

Updating the test when the number of fields changes is not a great chore, and is an opportunity to check that those changes have not affected your code.

---

Original version using method:

```
case class MyClass(i: Option[String], j: Option[Int], n: Option[OtherClass])
{
  def verify = {
    val c = this.productIterator.count{
      case o: Option[_] => o.nonEmpty
      case _ => true
    }
    i.nonEmpty && j.nonEmpty && c == 2
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea this would require updating every time a field was added. Also I don't control the case class so I can't add a verify method off of it although that is surmountable with a helper object or a type class. I figured out how to do this via the scala reflection API although I'm concerned about ordering. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `productIterator` as @Tim explains, however this smells kinda bad. If there is a special situation in which only `MyClass(Some(_), Some(_), None)` is valid, but `MyClass(Some(_), Some(_), Some(_))` is not, it appears that these should be two distinct types rather than a "catchall" class with ad-hoc validation tackled on the side.

Consider something like this:

```
    sealed trait Foo {
      def i: Option[String]
      def j: Option[Int]
      def n: Option[OtherClass] = None
   }

   case class IJ(iVal: String, jVal: Int) extends Foo {
      def i = Some(iVal)
      def j = Some(jVal) 
   }
   
   case class IJN(i: Option[String], j: Option[Int], nVal: OtherClass) extends Foo {
      override def n = Some(nVal)
   }
```

This way, you can simply check the type of the object you are dealing with to distinguish between the two situations:

```
     foo match { 
       case x: IJ => "i and j are defined, but n is not"
       case x: IJN => "N is defined, but i and j might not be"
    }
```

Comment: This feels more verbose than just manually checking each field and requires  updating every time.

Comment: Well, you cannot add fields to a class without updating it, so ... there's that. 
Re. "more verbose": I am not sure what made you think that, because it's ... not. But in any event, I don't think that "reducing verbosity" is a good candidate of the ultimate absolute goal of software design. Don't get me wrong, I _love_ brevity, and expressiveness, but adopting it as the main criteria for your design is taking it a bit too far even for me ...

Comment: Check my answer I think I found a way of doing this without having to update the method (only updating when a new allowable field is added) but I have concerns around ordering.

Comment: @UnitasBrooks ... yeah ... another possibility is to rewrite it in perl or javascript :) 
Sure, you can come up with all kinds of hacks ... it's just not how scala is intended to be used.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the hackiness of the solution? Is it that the reflection API is not recommended?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Reflection is a kind of a "meta-tool" you resort to (generally, when creating low-level libraries) for a specific reason, to address a specific issue that scala standard toolset does not provide for. But if you find yourself using it to write application code, then much more likely than not, you'd be much better off using a different language (among other things - like performance - it would also be much less verbose ;) ).

Answer (score -1):

I figured out you can do this through reflection, although it may not be recommended see note below:

```scala
val allowableFieldNames = Set("i", "j")   
val fields = universe.typeOf[MyClass].decls.collect {
   case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m.name.toString
 }.toList

val values = myClass.productIterator.toList

values.zip(fields).collect {
    case(o: Option[_], field: String) if !allowableFieldNames(field) => assert(o.isEmpty)  
}
```

This is assuming that `productIterator` and `universe.typeOf[].decls` return the parameters and their values in the same order.

From @Dima:
Reflection is a kind of a "meta-tool" you resort to (generally, when creating low-level libraries) for a specific reason, to address a specific issue that scala standard toolset does not provide for.

Comment: Doesn't this require an update when an "allowable" field is added? Or if a name is changed? What happens if a field is added that is neither allowable nor optional?
Also, in re. to your calling my solution "more verbose": you could just do `assert(myClass.isInstanceOf[IJ])` ;) ... (not that I am recommending it – you should use static typechecks instead – but it is certainly less verbose, than what you are doing).

Comment: Haha sorry I was not trying to be overly critical. I think from your other comment I see why this is not an ideal solution. I'm going to add that comment to this answer so future developers get some context on why it's not a great idea.

Comment: Nah, be critical all you want, that's fine. I am just saying that you were _wrong_ :)

Comment: I think it's more verbose than this reflection solution because everytime a new field is added to MyClass a new case class would need to be created to handle the new field. This could get out of hand quickly?

Comment: No offense but you'd better spend time to migrate to Scala 2.13 which offers `productElementNames`.

Comment: No, you don't need to create new case class every time, just keep adding the new fields to one of the existing ones if you prefer. Still better than having to add the field AND remember to update `allowableNames` list somewhere else.

Comment: @gael none taken, unfortunately that is not an option for me.